# SQLClientException - Where is the user defined?

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2010, wcf

I am testing a web service that communicates with a SQL server in Visual Studio 2010. While debugging, I received an error saying "Login failed for user MAINDOMAIN\MSP-SP$". The problem is that I don't recall defining a user with that name, and that user does not exist on the SQl server. Where is that user defined?

I am using Visual Studio 2010; I am debugging a WCF Service App. I am trying to communicate with a SQL server that has Windows Server 2008 and SQL Server management 2012.

Comment: The user name is defined in your connection string, you probably have integrated security turned on. Check out [Sql Connection Strings](https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/) to see if that helps.

Comment: Looks like a machine account name, which would usually happen if integrated security is enabled and the connection was being made from a service running as LocalSystem rather than your user. You can add machine accounts to SQL but it's probably better to define an explicit user account and connect with that.

Comment: I had a feeling it was something like that. I would prefer to specify a user account that can connect to SQL server with the right permissions. Where do I define the user account?

Comment: https://www.katieandemil.com/sql-server-2012-add-user-login-with-sql-server-authentication?tab=article

Comment: But you also have to make sure the SQL server is set up for mixed mode authentication, by default it's windows only